# Declare new routes from database field

Tags: java, spring

In my website, i have a table "projects" which contains a column "slug_url", I want to know how to define the new routes base on the projects in my table, so that each project can have a homepage.

I tried to autowired HttpSecurity class in my ProjectService class, that didn't work. I may have miss something in the documentation, I feel it's kind of basic but I could not find how to achieve this with Spring 5.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `@PathVariable` for that and this is how you do it:

In case you have already declared repository and service, you just have to autowire them and use findBy**ColumnName** functionality.

```
@Autowired ProjectService projectService;

@GetMapping("/project/{slug_url}")
protected ResponseEntity getProject(@PathVariable("slug_url") String slugUrl) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(projectService.findBySlugUrl(String slugUrl));
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I was so focused on delcaring these routes in my ConfigSecurity file.
I will handle everything security-related with annotations, thanks :)